# Mix and playback multiple tracks Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am creating a sound mixer in AS3. I have several sound samples that a user can choose from to create their own track. The mixer will "mixdown" a max of 4 tracks and playback the "mixed" track on demand. I'm having trouble getting the sounds to playback in sync. I'm new to working with sound in flash and wondering what I'm missing... Here is the "mix" function at present:

```
function mixIt(e:MouseEvent) {

    if (isPlaying) {
    channel1.stop();
            }
    var mChannel1:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel;
    var mChannel2:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel;

    var tUrl1:URLRequest = new URLRequest(trackChoice1);
    var tUrl2:URLRequest = new URLRequest(trackChoice2);
    var s1:Sound = new Sound();
    var s2:Sound = new Sound();

    var s1Done:Boolean = false;
    var s2Done:Boolean = false;

            s1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded1);
    s2.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded2);

            s1.load(tUrl1);
    s2.load(tUrl2);

    function onSoundLoaded1(e:Event) {
        s1Done = true;
        if (s2Done) {
        playMix()
        }
    }
    function onSoundLoaded2(e:Event) {
        s2Done = true;
        if (s1Done) {
            trace("s2 Done")
            playMix()
        }
    }
    function playMix(){
    mChannel1 = s1.play(0, 2);
    mChannel2 = s2.play(0, 2);
    //trace("MIXING TRACKS :" + tUrl1 + " + " + tUrl2);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try mixing sounds as byte arrays using [`Sound.extract()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#extract%28%29) and [`SampleDataEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/SampleDataEvent.html#data)

Comment: Ok, so I can individually extract the audio and it plays back no problem. But I'm having some difficulty in actually 'mixing' the sounds. Should I be storing the Bytes in a single sound Object to play back? is that possible? Sorry, new to sound in AS and there isnt a whole lot of documentation online. Pulling my hair out a bit :)

Comment: i'll have to try it myself to answer :) i'd try to create a new bytearray for `SampleDataEvent` from sums of bytes at the same position of source bytearrays